# Laravel new project custom url

Tags: php, laravel, url, custom-url

I am still new to Laravel.
I wanted to create a new laravel project. Thats done.
Then I wanted to make a custom local url.
I have 2 other projects running, also with a custom url.

I made the entry in the hosts file. Also in the homestead.yaml
hosts:

```
192.168.10.10  buchhaltung.at
```

homestead.yaml:

```
    - map: buchhaltung.at
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/buch/public
```

But the Url is not working...

The weird thing is, one of the other two projects doesn't have an entry in the `homestead.yaml` but does in the hosts file. And it's working...

Comment: Did you also run a "vagrant provision" once you were done?

Comment: no i didnt. Now its working. THX man!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `vagrant provision`? The URL in your `hosts` file and `homestead.yaml` are different. The URL must match, which URL do you want `buchhaltung.at` or `buch.at`?

Answer (score 0):

Your host file should looks like

192.168.10.10 buchhaltung.at

Edit--

In your `Homested.yaml` file `folder` section should look like this

```
folders:
    - map: /local-path-to-your/Code 
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/buch
```

Make sure you do `vagrant reload --provision` after making these changes.

Refer the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) for more information and I also found [another nice guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead) to getting started.

Comment: i mistyped. The entry in the hosts file is "192.168.10.10 buchhaltung.at" and its still not working...

Answer (score 0):

What was missing is to run "vagrant provision"!!